# Probability Homework Question

Tags: probability, self-study

A researcher is conducting a survey of county residents in a Midwestern state.
Foolishly, she uses lists of registered voters as a sampling frame and randomly draws
phone numbers and addresses from the lists. As it turns out, thirty-seven percent of
eligible adults are not registered to vote. In addition, of those registered to vote, seven
percent do not have accurate addresses or telephone contact information.
What percent of the county’s adults have a chance of being contacted by the
researcher? Describe your results.

Stuck on this need help on where to start. If i make a tree diagram what would be my prior probabilities?

Comment: You have a description of the problem. You will need to explain where your understanding is failing. See [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12)

Comment: Despite the appearance of the word "chance," this question is not about probabilities: it is only about proportions.

Answer (score 1):

From the first line of the problem 0.37 aren't registered to vote.

$P(\text{Not Registered}) = 0.37$
thus $P(\text{Registered}) = 0.63$

Of those registered to vote, 0.07 do not have accurate addresses:

$P(\text{No Contact| Registered}) = 0.07$ thus $P(\text{Contact| Registered})  = 0.93$

And what is being asked to be calculated is: $P(\text{Contact, Registered})$.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Could I also find P (A and B) (A=Registered B=Accurate Info). If I do that the answer i get is 58.59% have a chance of being contacted

Comment: Yes, and that is what is being asked, you have all the data setup above, only the calculation is missing for you to pursue.

Comment: Can you confirm my answer of 58.59% chance of being contacted?

Comment: Yes, that's what I get from my calculations.